# How to express x1*x2 in the quadprog of R

Tags: r, optimization

I have a question about how to express x1x2 in objective function.
Here is an example in the Internet.

```
##
## min x1^2 +2x2^2 + 4x3^2 - x1 - x2 + 5x3
## x1 + x3 <= 1
## x1 >= 5
## x2 <= 0
##

P = 2*diag (c (1, 2, 4));
d = c (-1, -1, 5);
A = matrix (0, nrow=3, ncol=3);
A[1,] = c(-1, 0, -1);
A[2,] = c( 1, 0, 0);
A[3,] = c( 0, -1, 0);
b = c(-1, 5, 0);
```

From the example, the objective finction is `x1^2 +2x2^2 + 4x3^2 - x1 - x2 + 5x3`

In R, it is `P = 2*diag (c (1, 2, 4)); d = c (-1, -1, 5);`

However, if i have an objective function like x1x2 or x1^2
How to key the commands in R ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: BTW, I think of another question why P = 2*diag (c (1, 2, 4)) this function "2" needs to multiply the diag?

Comment: The "2" is necessary because the non-linear part of objective function is multiplied by 1/2, see the solve.QP documentation and my answer for details

Answer (score 0):

`solve.QP` function minimizes the following expression:

```
min 1/2 * (t(x) %*% D %*% x) - t(d) %*% x
```

where x is the vector of `n` variables (e.g. x1, x2 ...), `D` a symmetric matrix of `n x n` coefficients and `d` a vector of `n` coefficients.

In order to understand how those matrix products translate to an objective function expression, I've created the following simple function to expand the quadprog objective given the inputs :

```
# Given matrix D and vector d that will be passed to solve.QP, 
# it returns the objective function expression as string
expandQPObj <- function(D, d, var.name = 'x') {
  # helper function that expands a matrix product. NB it does not compute the result, 
  # it just returns the expressions of each element of the resulting matrix
  expandMatrixProd <- function(m1, m2) {
    m1 <- as.matrix(m1)
    m2 <- as.matrix(m2)
    if (ncol(m1) != nrow(m2)) { stop("incompatible dimensions")  }
    n <- nrow(m1)
    m <- ncol(m2)
    res <- matrix('', nrow = n, ncol = m)
    for (i in 1:n) {
      for (j in 1:m) {
        a <- m1[i, ]
        b <- m2[, j]
        a <- ifelse(grepl('[+*]', a), paste0('(', a, ')'), a)
        b <- ifelse(grepl('[+*]', b), paste0('(', b, ')'), b)
        res[i, j] <- gsub('+-','-',paste(a, b, sep = '*', collapse = '+'),fixed = TRUE)
      }
    }
    return(res)
  }
  D <- as.matrix(D)
  d <- as.vector(d)
  n <- length(d)
  if (!all(dim(D) == n) || n == 0) {
    stop('Dimensions problem: D should be an nxn matrix and d a vector of length n (n>0)')
  }
  xvec <- paste(var.name, 1:n, sep = '')
  quadComp <- as.vector(Reduce(list(t(xvec), D, xvec),f=expandMatrixProd))
  linearComp <- as.vector(strMatrixMult(t(d), xvec))
  return(paste0('1/2*(', quadComp, ') - (', linearComp, ')'))
}
```

By calling it with literal coefficients we can easily understand how to set these coefficients to get our desired result :

```
Dliteral <- matrix(paste0('D',1:9),nrow=3,byrow = T)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] "D1" "D2" "D3"
#[2,] "D4" "D5" "D6"
#[3,] "D7" "D8" "D9"

dliteral <- paste0('d',1:3)
#[1] "d1" "d2" "d3"

expandQPObj(Dliteral,dliteral)
#"1/2*((x1*D1+x2*D4+x3*D7)*x1+(x1*D2+x2*D5+x3*D8)*x2+(x1*D3+x2*D6+x3*D9)*x3) - d1*x1+d2*x2+d3*x3"
```

So, in order to get :

```
min x1*x2
```

we need to set `D2=1 and D4=1` (not just `D2=2` since matrix `D` must be symmetric!) and all the others coefficients = 0, hence :

```
D = rbind(c(0,1,0),c(1,0,0),c(0,0,0))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    0    1    0
#[2,]    1    0    0
#[3,]    0    0    0
d <- rep(0,3)
#[1] 0 0 0

expandQPObj(D,d)
[1] "1/2*((x1*0+x2*1+x3*0)*x1+(x1*1+x2*0+x3*0)*x2+(x1*0+x2*0+x3*0)*x3) - 0*x1+0*x2+0*x3"
```

Similarly, to obtain :

```
min x1^2 (== min x1*x1)
```

we need to set `D1=2` and all the others coefficients = 0 :

```
D = rbind(c(2,0,0),c(0,0,0),c(0,0,0))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    2    0    0
#[2,]    0    0    0
#[3,]    0    0    0

d <- rep(0,3)
#[1] 0 0 0

expandQPObj(D,d)
# "1/2*((x1*2+x2*0+x3*0)*x1+(x1*0+x2*0+x3*0)*x2+(x1*0+x2*0+x3*0)*x3) - 0*x1+0*x2+0*x3"
```